# FB.logout() only from the application using javaScript SDK

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

I get a user's data using the Facebook JavaScript SDK like this:

```
FB.login(function(response){
    // some code here
    userid = response.authResponse.userId;
});
```

If the user id is odd (undesired one), then I call:

```
FB.logout();
```

This will make the user logout from my application and their Facebook account as well.

I want it to only log out the user out from my application. They should not be logged out from their Facebook account.

Below is the code I use to initialize the FB variable:

```
FB.init({appId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX', cookie: true, status: true, xfbml : true});
```

If a user logs in to my application then I get the response. The response has the status, access_token and user_id.

Which variable should I use to achieve only logging them out of my application and not Facebook?

Answer (score 0):

I am also having the same problem, looks like we need to use both PHP and Javascript SDK to get and maintain the state for App only logout. You can check out the tutorial [here](http://blog.straylightrun.net/2011/09/19/my-facebook-authentication-best-practices/), I am just looking into this, so I have not actually checked if it works.